# Using python oledump tool gives me "extraction failed" error

Tags: python, extract, ole

I would like some help with the oledump tool from the oletools python toolset.

I am doing a training exercise where I need to extract an attachment in a msg file and get the md5 hash for it. However I am having trouble extracting the attachment using oletools in a Linux environment. Keep in mind this is a training lab environment and I cannot get any other tools then the ones provided in the lab (oledump).

Checking the msg file, it clearly has an attachment (attach_version section) with binary data (ending in hex 0102)

[image: overview]

Checking section 3, it is a word doc

[image: section 3]

Section 4 seems to be the start of the binary data

[image: binary data]

However when I try to extract this part, I always get an extraction failed error. I tried the "-d" flag but that only gives me the section and not the whole file

[image: extraction]

How would be the best way to go about this to extract the file with oledump without the errors?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally worked this:
[python oledump extract file .docm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFG32.png)

- python3 oledump.py Salary-Ranges.msg -s4 -d > maldoc1.docm

MD5 checksum match to to task.

The '-e' argument probably is not designed for that job or just I don't know how to use correctly - still learning this tools.